# Bot Framework, Automatically add page to facebook channel

Tags: c#, facebook, botframework, bots

every time I add a page to my facebook application, I need to resend this form manually.

[Azure Panel Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTOgk.jpg)

But it is impossible to work like this, because I am developing an automatic and instantaneous integration.

Is there any way to automate this?

Comment: What’s this about, subscribing pages to your messenger bot webhook? That can be done via API, via the `/page/subscribed_apps` endpoint.

Comment: Do you want to configure Facebook Messenger credentials for your bot service and want to achieve it with automation commands or scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to install [Azure CLI 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/?view=azure-cli-latest) and add botservice extension, and then you can use the following command to create facebook channel through CLI.

```
az bot facebook create [-h] [--verbose] [--debug]
                              [--output {json,jsonc,table,tsv}]
                              [--query JMESPATH] --resource-group
                              RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME --name NAME --page-id
                              PAGE_ID --appid APP_ID --secret APP_SECRET
                              --token ACCESS_TOKEN
                              [--add-disabled [{true,false}]]
```